# Count number of lines in a cell/row in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm looking to count the number of unique lines/entries in a cell for a particular column in a dataframe row. Ideally I want the count for the number of unique lines/entry in each row. In the example below I have illustrated the entries as comma separated however in my data each entry is on a new line( with no comma):

For example if I have a dataframe like so:

```
ID            A            B
1           1,2,1,2      1,2,3,4
2           1,2,3,4      1,2,1,2
3           1,2,3        3,4
4           4,1
```

The expected out come should be similar to this:

```
ID            A            B           countA         countB 
1           1,2,1,2      1,2,3,4         2               4
2           1,2,3,4      1,2,1,2         4               2
3           1,2,3        3,4             3               2
4           4,1                          1               0
```

Any thoughts much appreciated I have looked at groupby, unique and size, however this is only applying to unique rows not entries inside a row. Hopefully my explanation is clear enough, thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for omit first row and count elementwise by [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) unique values by lengths of `set`s of splitted values:

```
#if missing values are NaNs
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(lambda x: len(set(x.split(','))) if isinstance(x, str) else 0)

#if missing values are empty strings
df1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].applymap(lambda x: len(set(x.split(','))) if x != '' else 0)
```

Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original `DataFrame` with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for rename columns:

```
df = df.join(df1.add_prefix('Count'))
print (df)
   ID        A        B  CountA  CountB
0   1  1,2,1,2  1,2,3,4       2       4
1   2  1,2,3,4  1,2,1,2       4       2
2   3    1,2,3      3,4       3       2
3   4      4,1      NaN       2       0
```

Comment: Another similar option could be `df['A_count'] = df['A'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension. Note a vectorised approach is not possible via Pandas, so if performance matters you should test different solutions.

Below we use `filter(None, ...)` to avoid counting empty strings.

```
def counter(x):
    return [len(set(filter(None, i.split(',')))) for i in x]

for col in ['A', 'B']:
    df['count'+col] = counter(df[col])

print(df)

   ID        A        B  countA  countB
0   1  1,2,1,2  1,2,3,4       2       4
1   2  1,2,3,4  1,2,1,2       4       2
2   3    1,2,3      3,4       3       2
3   4      4,1                2       0
```